# Using "-" to start files and not conflict with flags

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to replicate the "ls" command in C. It should take anywhere between 0 and 2 arguments, those being a file path and a set of flags. When 1 argument is passed, I am trying to distinguish between passing a file and passing a set of flags - I would have thought the obvious way to go about it was to assume no file names begin with a "-" character and so therefore, if the first character of the argument is a "-" then treat it as a set of flags, otherwise treat it as a file path.

How should I actually distinguish between the two?

Comment: `--` is used to end the switches and remove ambiguity. Otherwise `ls` just assumes switch.

Comment: Don't write everything yourself. Use the `getopt` library.

Answer (score 2):

well, the rule with ls is that — considering `-a` is a file:

- `ls -a` : `-a` is considered as an option argument ;
- `ls -- -a` : `-a` is considered as a file argument

the `--` argument is considered as a separator, after which all arguments are files, not options.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, programs *don't*, and leave it to the user to deal with the resulting problems.

For example, create a file called `-l`, and at least one other file, and then run `ls *`:

```
me@localhost:~$ mkdir temp
me@localhost:~$ cd temp
me@localhost:~/temp$ touch ./-l
me@localhost:~/temp$ touch testfile
me@localhost:~/temp$ ls *
-rw-rw-r-- 1 acampbell acampbell 0 Apr  4 11:00 testfile
me@localhost:~/temp$
```

`ls *` expanded to `ls -l testfile`.

Most Unix utilities can take the argument --, and *every argument* after `--` will be treated as a filename:

```
me@localhost:~/temp$ ls -l -- testfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 acampbell acampbell 0 Apr  4 11:00 testfile
me@localhost:~/temp$ ls -- -l testfile
-l  testfile
me@localhost:~/temp$
```

They can also specify a path that doesn't start with `-`, such as by using a redundant `./`:

```
me@localhost:~/temp$ ls ./*
./-l ./testfile
me@localhost:~/temp$
```

Comment: That;'s really interesting behaviour, thank you for explaining this :)